# Feedback on Set Theory Questions - Study Help

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I am doing some previous exams on Discrete Math as practice and I am just looking for some feedback on the answers as I don't think they are available publicly. I am reasonably confident on some, but situations where we take the union of a Set and another Set that contains the First or whether a Set contained by another Set is a subset confuse me a little.

$T = \{\varnothing\},\  Q = \{T\},\  R = \{T,\varnothing\},\  S = \{T,Q,R\}$

$Q ⊆ R:$       I said yes as every element appearing in $Q$ is in $R$

$R ⊆ S:$       I said no as the empty set does not appear in $S$ but I'm not sure

$\varnothing \in T:$        I said yes for obvious reasons

$\varnothing ⊆ T:$        I said yes because the empty set is a subset of everything

$T ∪ Q = \{\varnothing, \{\varnothing\}\}$

$T ∩ R = \{\varnothing\}$

Powerset($T$) $= \{\varnothing, \{\varnothing\}\}$ because $\varnothing$ and $\{\varnothing\}$ are distinct, right?

$|$Powerset($Q$)$| = 2$

$S ∪ R = \{T\}$

$T \times Q = \{(\varnothing,T)\}$

Could I get some feedback on these questions?

Comment: Everything is correct except $S\cup R=\{T,Q,R,\emptyset\}$. Perhaps you meant $S\cap R=\{T\}$?

Comment: It would perhaps help you more to note that $R=Q\cup T$.

Comment: $T\cup Q$ is wrong since $T\in Q$ so $T\in T\cup Q$... unless the $T\in Q$ is supposed to be the same $T=\{\emptyset\}$.  I assumed there was an abuse of notation and that letters were repeated.  If it is no abuse, then $Q=\{\{\emptyset\}\}$.  My understanding was that $T\cup Q=R$...

Comment: That was perhaps my fault. When I typed T∪Q={∅,{∅}} I meant T∪Q={∅,T} where T={∅}.